# Index Change event for Combobox of gridtemplateColumn in Telerik

Tags: c#, asp.net, combobox, telerik, radgrid

I can write a code.
In this I can take a Template Column & in this I build a RadCombobox.
When it's Index changed I want to affect the below text box.
Link the selected value of the Combo box is set as Text on Below TextBox.
Combo Box & Text Box are different Controls of Different Template Column.

I can Write Control of Combo box like this :

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="cmbGID" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource8" DataTextField="Name"
                        DataValueField="ID" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="cmbGID_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

But I don't know the parameters of this event like this :

```
protected void cmbGID_SelectedIndexChanged()
{
       //code...
}
```

Any one plz tell me that parameters & tell me is that possible to set txtValue.Text = cmbGID.SelectedValue.ToString()...???

Comment: Note: This all controls of Template Column are InsertItem Template...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution of this problem...

This is working by following code :

```
protected void cmbGrp_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, RadComboBoxSelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
{
    RadComboBox ddlCtrl = sender as RadComboBox;
    GridEditableItem dataItem = ddlCtrl.NamingContainer as GridEditableItem;
    RadComboBox cmbCtrl = dataItem.FindControl("cmbSetNo") as RadComboBox;
    RadTextBox txtCtrl = dataItem.FindControl("cmbSetNo") as RadTextBox;
    txtCtrl.Text = ddlctrl.SelectedValue.ToString();

    string query = "QUERY";

    ds.Clear();
    ds = c.getDataSet(query);

    cmbCtrl.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    cmbCtrl.DataTextField = "NO";
    cmbCtrl.DataValueField = "RecordID";
    cmbCtrl.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Hi, maybe it's a version reason, but now the working cast is: var editItem = cmbItem.NamingContainer as GridEditFormItem;

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
protected void vmbGID_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ddlCtrl = sender as RadComboBox;
    if (ddlCtrl != null)
    {
        var dataItem = ddlCtrl.Parent as GridDataItem;
        if (dataItem != null)
        {
            var txtCtrl = dataItem.FindControl("txtValue") as RadTextBox;
            if (txtCtrl != null)
            {
                txtCtrl.Text = ddlCtrl.SelectedValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to also fire a query by this & set DataSource, text , value field by this query.
for this I write :
`var cmbCtrl = dataItem.FindControl("cmbsetnumber") as RadComboBox;
        string qury = "QUERY";
        ds.Clear();
        ds = c.getDataSet(qury);
        cmbCtrl.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
        cmbCtrl.DataTextField = "NO";
        cmbCtrl.DataValueField = "RecordID";
        cmbCtrl.DataBind();`
Error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

@ : var cmbCtrl = dataItem.FindControl("cmbsetnumber") as RadComboBox;

plz tell me the solution 4 this..